# Por que o iframe não está sendo imprimido no input?

Tags: php, html

Tô colocando o conteúdo de um iframe num input, só que não aparece ele completo, aparece apenas isso no input text:

```
<iframe width=
```

E isso aparece na linha embaixo:

```
" type="text"/>
```

Vejam o código em que eu atualizo o campo "nome" e "iframe", na hora de aparecer o que tá registrado em iframe é que tá dando problema, o iframe não aparece todo no input:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<div id="box">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header_logo">
            <a href="painel.php"><img src="../images/DCDesenvolvimento.png" alt="" border="0"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="menu">
            <?php include("menu.php");?>
        </div>

        <div id="conteudo">
            <span class="caminho">Home &raquo; Editar Vídeos</span>
            <h1>Cadastrar Post</h1>
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['cadastrar_post']) && ($_POST['cadastrar_post'] == "cad"))
            {
                $id_a_editar = strip_tags(trim($_POST['id_do_post']));
                $nome = strip_tags(trim($_POST['nome']));
                $iframe = $_POST['iframe'];
                $editar_posts = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE baterista 
                                                            SET nome = '$nome', video = '$iframe'
                                                                WHERE id = '$id_a_editar'")or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
                if($editar_posts>=1)
                {
                    echo "<div class=\"ok\">Seu tópico foi atualizado com sucesso!</div>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<div class=\"no\">Seu tópico não foi atualizado</div>";
                }
            }

            $editar_post_id = $_POST['id_do_post'];

            $dados = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT id, nome, video 
                                                FROM baterista WHERE id = '$editar_post_id'")or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
            if(mysqli_num_rows($dados) == 0)
            {
                echo "Não encontramos notícias nesse momento";
            }
            else
            {
                while($res_videos = mysqli_fetch_array($dados))
                {
                    $id_do_post = strip_tags(trim($res_videos[0]));
                    $nome = strip_tags(trim($res_videos[1]));
                    $iframe = $res_videos[2];
?>
            <form name="cadastrar_posts" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return valida()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset>
                                        <span>Nome</span>
                    <input name="nome" value="<?=$nome?>" id="nome" type="text"/>
                    <span id="avisonome"></span>
                    <span>Iframe</span>
                    <input name="iframe" value="<?php echo $iframe;?>" type="text"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cadastrar_post" value="cad"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="cadastro_btn" name="editar"/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
<?php
                }
            }
?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está dando conflito com as aspas duplas da string `$iframe`, que é um código HTML que possui atributos usando aspas duplas, com as aspas duplas do `value=""`. Isso está causando uma quebra no delimitador (aspas duplas) do atributo `value` do input.

Seu código está ficando algo assim:

```
<input name="iframe" value="<iframe width="100%"></iframe>" type="text"/>
```

Veja que as aspas do `width` conflitam com as aspas delimitadoras do `value`.

Você pode resolver isso de forma simples apenas trocando as aspas duplas do `value` por aspas simples:

```
<input name="iframe" value='<?php echo $iframe;?>' type="text"/>
                           ↑                     ↑
```

Com isso não haverá a quebra do delimitador do `value`, ficando assim:

```
<input name="iframe" value='<iframe width="100%"></iframe>' type="text"/>
```

Ou usando a função [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
<input name="iframe" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($iframe);?>" type="text"/>
```